# Javascript Lightbox, Show Caption and Keyboard Navigation problem

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have this javascript lightbox, but it has two issues. 
First I have make probably a mistake, where it supposes to show the alt text of the image.

```
function openGallery($gallery, imageIndex = 0) {
const $galleryThumbnails = $gallery.find('img');
const $galleryElement = $(`
<div class="gallery-lightbox">
<button class="gallery-close">✖</button>
<button class="gallery-next">❱</button>
<button class="gallery-preview">❰ </button>
<div class="gallery-image-container">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="gallery-status"></div>
</div>
  `);

$galleryElement.prependTo(document.body);

// This part shows the image
function showFullImage(){
const fullImageUrl = $galleryThumbnails
  .eq(imageIndex)
  .attr('data-full-image');

$galleryElement
  .find('.gallery-image-container > img')
  .attr('src', fullImageUrl);

 // Show Text Code that don't work
  $galleryElement
  .find('.gallery-image-container > img') 
  .attr('alt', alt);
}
```

Secondly for the keyboard navigation, I want also to to close the gallery with esc. I tried several ways but I didn't make it work. Could anyone suggest a solution ?

```
function nextSlide() {
imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % $galleryThumbnails.length;
showFullImage();
}


$galleryElement
.find('.gallery-next')
.click(() => nextSlide());


$galleryElement
.find('.gallery-preview')
.on('click', () => {
imageIndex = imageIndex === 0 ? $galleryThumbnails.length - 1 :
  imageIndex - 1;

showFullImage();
});

$galleryElement
.find('.gallery-close')
.click(() => $galleryElement.remove());

showFullImage();
}

// Code for keyboard navigation
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    document.querySelector('.gallery-next').click();
}
else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    document.querySelector('.gallery-preview').click();
}       
};

$('[data-gallery] > img')
.click((event) => {
const $gallery = $(event.target).parent();
const $items = $gallery.find('img');
const index = $items.index(event.target);
openGallery($gallery, index);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add alt text to your image you could use the [alt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) property or the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method like:

```
image.alt = "Alt text here";
```

or

```
image.setAttribute("alt","Alt text here");
```

To use the esc key you have to do something like this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {
        alert('Pressed esc key!');
    }
});
```

or use the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event like:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 27) {
        alert('Pressed esc key!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Esc key warms like a charm ;-)

Comment: For the alt text, because it's a lightbox gallery i want to change every time, so i need to get it from html. So the code i have now is 
  $galleryElement
  .find('.gallery-image-container > img') 
  .attr('alt', alt);

Comment: I tried this 

  $galleryElement
  .find('.gallery-image-container > img') 
  .attr('alt', alt);

but it don't seem to work. Maybe i have a typo ?

Comment: try this maybe: $galleryElement .find('.gallery-image-container > img') .attr('alt', 'alt');

Comment: It's the same that I have on previous comment (wrong paste?). Either way it's not working, maybe i miss something else in the code.

Comment: .attr('alt', alt) -> .attr('alt', 'alt'). That was the difference. Ok then put your code on jsfiddle so i can work on it.

Comment: ok. The way i said above is working. like this https://jsfiddle.net/v3kf091w/ but the thing is that you want to have different alt for all the images. You have to use an alt variable. In your example you use a variable that is never defined. So you use your variable to produce you alt text and then use it like you already have it .attr('alt', alt)

Comment: And this is the other example i was talking about https://jsfiddle.net/v3kf091w/1/. Don't forget to pick the answer and upvote it! Goodnight

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you show me the way to do this, so it works fine ? (I want the alt caption to be seen under the picture in lightbox) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this, but I see not text in lightbox at all...

var alt = this.$currentTarget.attr('alt');
$('.gallery-image-container > img').attr('alt', alt );